# Why WAS is looking for ejb jar xml for an EJB 3 application

Tags: ejb-3.0

When I try to deploy my EJb 3.0 EAR on WAS 6.1,  iget :

```
The EAR file could be corrupt and/or incomplete. Make sure that the application is at a compatible Java 2 Platform, Enterprise Edition (J2EE) Level for WebSphere Application Server.
AppDeploymentException: [META-INF/ejb-jar.xml] org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.DeploymentDescriptorLoadException: META-INF/ejb-jar.xml
```

But this is an EJB 3.0 application, so why does it look for ejb-jar.xml?

Comment: ejb-jar.xml is optional in EE5, but WAS 6.1 [doesn't support EJB3 / EE5](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp) if [the right feature pack](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21287579) isn't installed.  Is it installed on your server?

Comment: Thanks...I typed in versionInfo.sh and got:Installed Product -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Name WebSphere Application Server Version 6.1 Feature Pack f or EJB 3.0 Version 6.1.0.35 ID EJB3 Build Level cf351045.02 Build Date 11/7/10 .....so it does support